# Calendar Notifications as Alarms

Tags: applications, google, google-calendar

Is there any way to have calendar event notifications show up as alarms?  Maybe via some 3rd party app?

I saw a rec here, but the reviews indicate that the app is not maintained and dysfunctional:
https://mondegreen2.blogspot.ca/2014/06/google-calendar-reminder-as-smartphone.html

I can't reliably notice notifications, since they are too short, so I make alarms for important meetings, but this is getting really inconvenient.

I also tried the "Calendar Notifications" app, but haven't been able to get it to help (it just adds another notification :P)

I also tried "Alarm Calendar Plus", which seems to work, except that it doesn't properly update when I add new events.  (also the UI is difficult)
**https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moyou.acplus&hl=en**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Alarm Calendar Plus, but it didn't seem to work properly.
**https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moyou.acplus&hl=en**

I'm now using the premium version of Business Calendar, which allows you to set the notification to repeat many times, and snooze the notification.  I think it still uses the notification volume, but is serving my purpose.
http://www.businesscalendar.de/